# Django to Heroku, How to migrate sqlite3 data to postgres

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, heroku

I tried to host a website on heroku but I keep getting this error

> File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 84, in _execute
> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "home_product" does not
> exist LINE 1: ...home_product"."price", "home_product"."slug" FROM
> "home_prod...

whenever I tried to use

```
heroku run python
manage.py migrate -a appname
```

I mainly used [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UkokhawLKDU&t=964s) as a reference to hosting.

and also [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51775331/heroku-django-database-error) and [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Deployment) didn't shed much light on the issue.

Here's my `settings.py`

```
"""
Django settings for Corbett_Jewelry project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""


from pathlib import Path
import os
import django_heroku
import dj_database_url
from decouple import config
import psycopg2

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', '') != 'False'


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Corbett_Jewelry.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Corbett_Jewelry.wsgi.application'

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600, ssl_require=True)

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

My `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    desc = models.TextField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Images(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name

    
class Beads(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='beads/')
```

My Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn Corbett_Jewelry.wsgi
```

My `requirements.txt`:

```
asgiref==3.4.1
cycler==0.10.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.2.9
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
kiwisolver==1.3.2
matplotlib==3.4.3
numpy==1.21.2
Pillow==8.3.2
psycopg2==2.9.2
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-decouple==3.5
pytz==2021.3
selenium==3.141.0
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
urllib3==1.26.7
whitenoise==5.3.0
```

I don't know what else information you might need to solve this. I'm happy to provide any info since I've been banging my head over this for a week now.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with what you are attempting. You do not seem to be transferring data from `sqlite3` to `postgres` as your question title suggests...are you simply trying to instantiate a new instance of your app using postgres instead of SQLite? I am just about 100% sure your issue is in the way you are attempting to connect to the database as it cannot run migrations, but I do not know what is being returned by `dj_database_url` to setup your  `DATABASES` attr in settings, can you show that?

Comment: @ViaTech So I titled it that way because I read somewhere from someone having a similar problem where they got a reply telling them it was a transfer problem. Also I'm not quite sure how I could show that but when I tried printing ```dj_database_url.config```  it returned an empty dictionary

Comment: I think you'd have more success getting help if you pruned your example down. Maybe start a new question, but make sure you have a [MRE] (and delete the old one so you don't create duplicates)

Comment: @Neuron Hey thanks for the advise will do that in a while, also saw that you fixed the formatting on my question, super nice of you to do that, thanks!

Comment: Sure thing. Glad I could help. While we are on the topic of suggestions.. People on StackOverflow tend to address one another in a more professional manner. I would not call strangers "bro". Especially if you don't even know their gender ;)

Comment: @Neuron Ah yeah that makes sense will keep that in mind next time around, but I do honestly consider 'bro' to be a gender neutral term

Answer (score 0):

@Gamingapple... as you asked in the comments, I will attempt to provide all possible solutions I can think of for your issue.

**I have never use Heroku, but here are the first solutions I would try**:

**1.** A quick read from Heroku's help docs is showing you perhaps are not running migrations in the way that Heroku thinks are best practices for migrations: https://help.heroku.com/GDQ74SU2/django-migrations there (more-or-less) means you should be running your migrations locally, pushing up to Git, and then Heroku will automate the running of your migrations on deploy where it states:

```
Then, add the following as the first line in your Procfile:

release: python manage.py migrate
```

But note that this also means you should be using Postgres locally in development, not SQLite (as your title suggests).

-- Along with this, it appears you are trying to run migrations by app when you do: `manage.py migrate -a appname`, Django does have some regular migrations that need to be run so I'd just try `manage.py migrate`

**2.** You noted in the comment that `dj_database_url.config()` from PyPi's `dj_database_url` package: https://pypi.org/project/dj-database-url/ is returning an empty dictionary. To me, without extra info, I would say this is where your problem is when you manually try to run `migrate` in your Heroku instance; there is no database to find or connect to. To fix this I would remove the use of `dj_database_url` (as I have not used it either and we are debugging), and manually write my connection string for Django's `DATABASES`, like so:

`pip install psycopg2` or just ensure it is in requirements/installed.

Change your `DATABASES` attr in settings to be manually written so you know what it is (we are debugging so perhaps after you get it up you make the password gathering more secure, like as an env variable)

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
       'NAME': '[HEROKU DB NAME]',
       'USER': '[HEROKU DB USERNAME]',
       'PASSWORD': '[HEROKU PASSWORD]',
       'HOST': '{HEROKU HOST IP OR NAME FOR YOUR DB]',
       'PORT': '[HEROKU DB PORT]',
   }
}
```

Now with that correct, run the migration commands:

`python manage.py makemigrations`

`python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Hey thanks for trying but I seemed to have made things worse for myself trying to fix this problem, The app seems to crash before it even starts and shows, "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'corbettjew'" on the logs, I've tried undoing the changes in git but it still didn't fix it, no clue what to do now

Comment: Well `corbettjew` is not a PyPi package so you are appearing to import it somewhere or attempting to load it from somewhere else and since it doesn't exist you are getting Module Not Found errors.

Comment: @Gamingapple, also if this is just something you are attempting to get live on Heroku, and you have no clue what you've done wrong, and it's not important... why not just trash your current project and go with a better tutorial on the full process of getting this completed? Here looks to be a solid one: https://www.codementor.io/@jamesezechukwu/how-to-deploy-django-app-on-heroku-dtsee04d4

Comment: It's just a personal project thing so I'll probably do that now thanks for all the help!